# Prove that $D$ is bijective with the integers set $ℤ$

Tags: real-analysis, roots

Let $f:ℝ→ℝ$ be a real analytic function. Assume that $f$ has infinitely many zeros. Let $D$ be the set of those zeros. Prove that $D$ is bijective with the integers set $ℤ$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f=0$, $f$ is analytic and $D$ is uncountable. Otherwise, $D$ is a discrete set; because $\mathbb{R}$ is separable, $D$ is at most countable.